# Keywords and MSC Classification in LaTeX article class

Tags: article, amsart

In the amsart document class, one has the commands `\keywords{foo}` and `\subjclass{foo}`. I was wondering, how does one make similar commands for the standard LaTeX article class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `amsart` commands are defined to create commands `\@keywords` and `\@subjclass`, which are then used to typeset footers in the `\maketitle` command. You could hack the `\maketitle` command provided by the `article` class (or even better, redefine it in a class of your own) to provide similar functionality, but it's easier (and sloppier) to hack the `\@title` command:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\subjclass}[2][1991]{%
  \let\@oldtitle\@title%
  \gdef\@title{\@oldtitle\footnotetext{#1 \emph{Mathematics subject classification.} #2}}%
}
\newcommand{\keywords}[1]{%
  \let\@@oldtitle\@title%
  \gdef\@title{\@@oldtitle\footnotetext{\emph{Key words and phrases.} #1.}}%
}
\makeatother
```

*These definitions are **very** hacky and likely require correct ordering of things (and as I said you really should either hack the `\maketitle` command properly or extend `article` with your own class). Most importantly, use `\keyword` and `\subject` **after** `\title`. But it works.*

Comment: You should use `\newcommand` instead of `\gdef` whenever you can.

Comment: I tried to use this, there is one problem: accented letters like ó or ñ do not work within these commands, even when things are set up so they work well in the rest of the document!

Answer (score 3):

If all you want is a footnote with no marks, you can write:

```
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}} 
\footnotetext{\emph{Key words} whatever}     
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
```